# Save html file as aspx

Tags: html, asp.net

Hi we've just moved to sharepoint and I need to convert all  my html pages to aspx, I've looked in Sublime and Notepad ++ and I can't see an option to save in this format  just asp (amongst a million other formats) any pointers in how to do this, i'm sure there is a really simple answer that i'm missing!

Comment: aspx is just a text file format anyway. So just change the extension to aspx. Of course, there is also specific content you have to put in an aspx file to make it interpretable as such by the server - it's part of the asp.net webforms framework and may include code executed server-side, and so on. I think it's not as simple as just renaming the files really. And...are you sure you actually even need to do that? Surely SharePoint can host and display HTML files as-is. It depends on the details of what you're actually trying to do with them, I suppose.

Comment: If you genuinely want to make your site into a fully-fledged sharepoint site you might be better to create a sharepoint project in Visual Studio and work with it from there, and copy the relevant parts of your existing HTML into the new format. But you probably need to do a little bit of study of tutorials etc if you haven't worked with it before. SharePoint is not a simple thing. I'm not an expert in it by any means but I do know it's not a simple case of renaming some files and then it all magically works.